# как убрать соотношения сторон?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет, есть сайт, на котором работает калькулятор расчета стоимости за м2, нужно убрать соотношения сторон, но я не могу понять, где в коде оно прописывается, пожалуйста помогите, вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //general variables
  $width = $('#width_value');
  $height = $('#height_value');
  $result = $('#result');
  var maintainAspectRatio = true,
      borderChecked = false,
      border_koef = 0;

  //init dropzone for user image
  Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
    init: function () {
      this.on("complete", function (file) {
        $('#layout').attr("src", 'photos/cat_3/f/'+file.name);
        maintainAspectRatio = false;
      });
      this.on("addedfile", function() {
        if (this.files[1]!=null){
          this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
        }
      });
    },
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Перетягніть зображення для завантаження',
    dictInvalidFileType: 'Підтримуються тільки файли зображень',
    dictResponseError: 'Не вдалося завантажити файл - спробуйте ще раз',
  };

  calculateValue(); //calculate on load

  //number inputs handlers
  $width.change(function() {
    if(maintainAspectRatio) {
      $height.val(Math.round($width.val() / parameters.picture_aspects_ratio));
    };
    
    calculateValue();
  });

  $height.change(function() {
    if(maintainAspectRatio) {
      $width.val(Math.round($height.val() * parameters.picture_aspects_ratio));
    }
    
    calculateValue();
  });

  //show border select panel
  $('#show-border-select').click(function() {
    $('#border-select').toggle();

    $('#show-border-select').html($('#show-border-select').text() == 'Додати рамку' ? 'Забрати рамку' : 'Додати рамку');

    borderChecked = (borderChecked == true) ? false : true;
    calculateValue();
  })

  //radiobuttons handler
  $('[name="border-select"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      borderChecked = true;
      border_koef = $(this).attr('data-border-koef');
      calculateValue();
    }
  });

  //main function - call it on every change
  function calculateValue() {
    var result = $width.val()*$height.val()*parameters.picture_price_koef;

    if(borderChecked) {
      result += $width.val()*$height.val()*border_koef;
    }

    result = (Math.round(result*100/100) / 100).toFixed(2);

    $result.html(result);
  }
});
```

```html
 <script>
  var param=0.73;
    //Тут задаються параметри картинки
    var parameters = {
      'picture_price_koef': '0.098', //коефіцієнт ціни картини
      'picture_aspects_ratio': false, //співвідношення сторін картини = ширина / висота;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Вот сам сайт https://www.gallery.lviv.ua/calculator.php?id=23&lang=1

Comment: Соотношение сторон чего нужно убрать?

Comment: соотношения размера, если на сайте ввести ширину 40 то и высота автоматом будет 40, нужно что бы все можно вводить вручную

Comment: Калькулятор на сайте работает некорректно. У меня при вводе одной стороны значение сторой просто пропадает. Цена не меняется.

Comment: пробуйте еще раз

Answer (score 1):

Присваивание значений после изменения ширины или высоты происходит после проверки переменной `maintainAspectRatio` (в 33 строке и 41 строка)

измените ее на false и будет так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Если я поставлю здесь (  var maintainAspectRatio = true,),false то это ничего не даст, я пробовал

Comment: а не все ок ,спасибо надо было отключить кэш такую проблему создал, все спасибо!